# SVG image clipping mask after reflection

Tags: svg

I'm currently generating the following svg:

```
<!--add full image for reference-->
<image id="refImageMirror" x="0" y="0" class="dot" width="500" height="500" opacity="1" xlink:href="http://www.nyweamet.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/0942a__grandCentralStationExterior.jpg" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0, -500)"></image>

<!--add full path for reference-->
<path id="refPathMirror" class="geom" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-210)" d="M200,0A200,200 0 0,1 141.4213562373095,141.42135623730948L0,0Z" style="fill: none; stroke: black"></path>

<use id="clippedImage" xlink:href="#refImageMirror" clip-path="url(#myMirrorClipper)"></use>

<clipPath id="myMirrorClipper">
        <use xlink:href="#refPathMirror"></use>
</clipPath>
```

However, the clipped image differs from what is directly below the path. I think this might have to do with how the transformations of the clipping path and of the image interact. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question, but your comments in the code "image/path for reference" look to me like you don't want them to actually be rendered directly, but only to be used later as a clip path and a clipped image. So, you might want to put them into a `<defs>` element ([try on Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/yom9zRSS)) because otherwise you'd get an overlay of a clipped image on top of an unclipped image, which means the clipped image is "concealed".

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="250px">
  <defs>
    <image id="refImageMirror" x="0" y="0" class="dot" width="500" height="500" opacity="1" xlink:href="http://www.nyweamet.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/0942a__grandCentralStationExterior.jpg" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0, -500)"></image>
    <path id="refPathMirror" class="geom" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-210)" d="M200,0A200,200 0 0,1 141.4213562373095,141.42135623730948L0,0Z" style="fill: none; stroke: black"></path>
  </defs>

  <clipPath id="myMirrorClipper">
          <use xlink:href="#refPathMirror"></use>
  </clipPath>
  <use id="clippedImage" xlink:href="#refImageMirror" clip-path="url(#myMirrorClipper)"></use>
</svg>
```

**Edit**: It turns out the the OP's problem is a Chrome bug.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the reply. I'm rendering the reference image to clarify the problem. Given the reference path and reference image, I would expect a different result from the clipping mask.

Comment: I would expect the path to result in a clipped image consisting of pixels inside the path. Instead, we're getting a clipped image from a different area of the original image. In other words, I would expect the result of my code to be just the original image with a black outline showing the path. Thanks so much for getting back to me.

Comment: This is exactly what I get with all browsers (Firefox, IE9, Opera, Safari/Windows) except for Chrome/Chromium. (It helps to try a few different browsers.) This is not a really satisfactory answer, but the only thing you might be able to do is file a bug report for Chromium, or avoid transformations.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot. I unfortunately cannot avoid transformations for this project. I just filed a bug report with Chrome.